# Can TestDisk utility recover data

Tags: filesystem, data-recovery, testdisk

Actually I want know , can Testdisk recover data after fresh installation of new Ubuntu OS 16.04 from a deleted partition.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Each case is specific. In principle yes, it can. But we need to know precisely how the situation is. Please update your question with the detailed information on the partitions before and after the fact. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer which is very hard to say, only way to find out is to try a recovery.

But to be honest it is very unlikely since the new installation most likely overwrote existing data in most cases and if there is really something to recover it may be mostly partial and or incomplete.

So as a final verdict i would rather say if you're not willing to spend countless money on specialists in data recovery you should chalk the data up onto a new lesson learned: **always make backups!**